# Searching for website addresses under specific circumstances?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search for website addresses. I can't figure out why I can't get my regex to work. The websites will begin with either http:// or https:// or either of those with www. after, or just www. before the address, or sometimes nothing before the address. I don't want to capture any of that if it's there.

The end of the address should be followed by either a / or white space or end of line (I only want the domain, so I don't want to capture any of the address that includes `/`).

This was my last attempt: `(?:http(?:s)?://)?(?:www\.)?(\S+\.[A-z\-\.]+)(?:/| |$)`.

I originally had `\S+` after the `\.` too instead of the `[]` and that wasn't working either. It *usually* worked but sometimes doesn't. One specific instance is an address with a `-` in it and a few `\.` in different places. The regex only captured up to the `-` and I can't figure out why it decided not to capture that or after it, which is why I tried to include it in what was allowed after the `\.`.

Comment: Regex seems to be working, you got to escape your / with \. Check this https://regex101.com/r/Sel5uZ/1

Comment: I'm testing it out a few times with - addresses and it's still not working right. If I search a string with only that address it finds it, but if there's other addresses it skips over it and chooses an address without the -. I can't understand why it's doing that.

Comment: Please share negative test strings

Comment: I've figured it out! The last non-capturing group to end the output wasn't correct. I had to include \b because apparently this one address oddly didn't have anything after it that the regex was detecting like end of line or space (and I can't check the string myself manually) so it was registering as not a match. I think it just happened to have a - in it. So now the last non-capturing group is (?:\b|\/) and it's working correctly so far after trying it multiple times. If you want to post this as the answer I'll accept it and upvote since you were the only one trying to help me, and thanks!